# Title on marker in android google map is not displayed

Tags: java, android, google-maps

In my android application I've added `setOnMarkerClickLister` on `GoogleMap`'s object to display Toast notification. However now, the marker's title is not displayed. What could be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void initilizeMap()
{
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your current location is" +
                    marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to return false so the system handles the click on the marker, thus showing the info window:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yout current location is"+marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```